# How to find id of dynamically created radio groups and each have 4 radio buttons

Tags: android

How to find id of dynamically created radio groups and each radio button have 4 radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can set id for every View by `setId(int)` and then search by it. But remember to put in layout views without same Ids.

Answer (score 0):

Declare RadioButton array as globle

for example

```
RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[4]; // declare as globle
```

Change

```
 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                                            switch (checkedId) {
                                                case R.id.option_1:
                                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Option 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                case R.id.option_2:
                                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Option 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                case R.id.option_3:
                                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Option 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                case R.id.option_4:
                                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Option 4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            }
```

with

```
@Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
                        {
                            if(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == rb[0].getId())
                            {

                            }
                            else if(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == rb[1].getId())
                            {

                            }

                        }
```

Comment: radio_button_id. is id that you have to give to your radio button

Comment: Actually i added radio button also dynamic...then how to find that?..i am using radiobutton.setID(i) like that.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                rb[i] = new RadioButton(mContext);
                rb[i].setId(i);
                rb[i].setText(mNavItems.get(position).mOpt[i]);
                rb[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                mNavItems.get(position).newGroup.addView(rb[i], p);

            }

Comment: can't you do rb[i].getId()  means instead of  R.id.radio_button_id?

Comment: It's my OnCreateView() code..                                                                                                             final RadioGroup[] rgl = new RadioGroup[4];
        for (int k = 0; k < questions.length; k++) {
            rgl[k] = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
            rgl[k].setId(k);
            if (k == 0) {
                mNavItems.add(new NavItem(questions[k], questions1_option, rgl[k]));
            }

Comment: may u send your mail id

Comment: You can post it here.

Comment: ArrayList<NavItem> mNavItems = new ArrayList<NavItem>();
    ListView listView;
    public RadioButton radio_b;
    public RadioGroup ans;
    String[] questions = {"Who Developed C?", "What is your Name?", "What is the use of getChar()?", "How many Keywords are in c?"};
    String[] questions1_option = {"Dennis Ritchie", "Ashok Kamthene", "Bala Guru Samy", "John"};
    String[] questions2_option = {"XXXXX", "YYYYY", "ZZZZZ", "AAAAA"};
    String[] questions3_option = {"Getting Characters", "Print Characters", "Error", "Not Defined"};
    String[] questions4_option = {"32", "23", "1", "104"};